# Gatsby: Calling `touchNode` on page node throws 'TypeError: locationAndPageResources.pageResources is undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Calling touchNode on a page (from a source plugin) causes the following error when you go to the hopefully cached page:

> TypeError: locationAndPageResources.pageResources is undefined

[touchNode call:](https://github.com/NathHorrigan/gatsby-source-wagtail/blob/feature/cache/src/gatsby-node.js#L47)

```
// Code here checks if the page node in Gatsby cache is the same version 
// as backend version. If so 'touch it' and don't recreate.
await Promise.all(result.data.pages.map(async page => {
    const pageCacheKey = `cache-${page.url}`
    const cacheResult = await pageRecords.getKey(pageCacheKey)
    if (cacheResult) {
        const node = pageNodes.find(node => {
            if (!node.context)
                return
            return node.context.url == page.url
        })

        if (node) {
            if (node.context.lastPublishedAt == page.lastPublishedAt) {
              pageRecords.setKey(pageCacheKey, localPublishedAt)
              return touchNode({
                nodeId: node.id
              })
            }
        }
    }
  }))
```

#### Expected result

Page Node should persist without having to recreate it (and without requiring backend).

#### Actual result

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error after deleting my index.js file.
I ran `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop`. This solved the problem.